# Use deeplearnig4j library

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deeplearning4j

I need to use **deeplearning4j** library in a new java project.

I downloaded .jar (in particoular deeplearning4j-core and ndj4-api-platform) from maven library.

I imported that in eclipse

I receive an error because *org.ndj4.api.complex.IComplexNumber* is not found.

Where may I find a *.jar* with that **classes?**

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.nd4j

Comment: I already watched there, but there's no jar with IComplexNumber class.

Comment: It's in the API Jar http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.nd4j/nd4j-api/0.0.3.5/org/nd4j/linalg/api/complex/IComplexNumber.java

Comment: Ok that is what I meant! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please import our examples and use maven (or some build system):
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/

I say this due to the sheer number of jars you need for running dl4j.
I would consider using maven rather than avoiding it.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

We say all of this right in the deeplearning4j quickstart:
http://deeplearning4j.org/quickstart

I would suggest reading the docs for the project rather than trying to figure it out yourself. You are only wasting time by doing that.